# WSO2 Identity Server: Error while loading identity configurations after editing identity.xml

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to set up an WSO2-Identity Server. I've downloaded the Version 4.0.0 Binary. It started correctly and I was able to use it with LDAP.

However, if I want to insert the correct ServerURL into the identity.xml file I get an error.

I inserted the follwoing into the identity.xml:

```
<OpenIDServerUrl>https://server.vm.uni-freiburg.de:9443/openidserver</OpenIDServerUrl>
<OpenIDUserPattern>https://server.vm.uni-freiburg.de:9443/openid/</OpenIDUserPattern>
```

and when starting the wso2 IS the following error is thrown:

```
[2012-11-23 10:34:41,510] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser} -  Error while loading Identity Configurations
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream Closed


    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildElementIterator.next(OMChildElementIterator.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.readChildElements(IdentityConfigParser.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.<init>(IdentityConfigParser.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityConfigParser.getInstance(IdentityConfigParser.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil.populateProperties(IdentityUtil.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.ui.internal.SAMLSSOUIBundleActivator.start(SAMLSSOUIBundleActivator.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:782)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream Closed
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:708)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1086)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ISOLatinReader.read(ISOLatinReader.java:79)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:84)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:57)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMoreFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:1046)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMoreFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:1053)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextCharFromCurrent(StreamScanner.java:811)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readEndElem(BasicStreamReader.java:3206)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2832)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
    ... 23 more
```

However, if I leave the default values:

```
    <OpenIDServerUrl>https://localhost:9443/openidserver</OpenIDServerUrl>
    <OpenIDUserPattern>https://localhost:9443/openid/</OpenIDUserPattern>
```

the server starts normally.

I've found a Bug-Report from https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-407 which may be connected with the problem but is not the same.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!